# Bootstrap Modal not showing the dialog

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to implement a Bootstrap Modal for quite some time now. I've followed the instructions in the bootstrap documentation but I still can't get it right. Why doesn't this work [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq50wdn9/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did u include jquery?

Comment: Yes I did. Popper.js, JQuery and JQuery-ui are all included.

Comment: i don’t see it in jsfiddle. when i included it and model box worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run bootstrap you need to use jquery. Updated on below code and 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq50wdn9/1/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is very confusing, my code works if I put it in a jsFiddle but wont work in my project. I right clicked on the page of my project and I copied the source code and pasted it in a jsFiddle and the Bootstrap Modal worked. In my project, when I click on the "Launch Demo Modal" button, the page foreground becomes dark as if the Modal is about to show, but it never does.

Comment: Check the order of jquery and Bootstrap,  or some other external CSS or javascript library blocking your model. Click the show model button and inspect the model div z-index and other class CSS styles